# How do I use my own AWS Lambda function that I unpacked and edited?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zip

I used this tutorial

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/resize-an-image-in-aws-s3-using-lambda-function-dc386afd4128

In it, there's a link to a zip file that I simply copy pasted to my lambda, and the function works. However, I wanted to make slight changes, so I unpacked it, made changes, and packed it again. Now, Lambda can't unpack it anymore. I guess they use some different zip method? I just used winrar. I'm not really sure HOW to pack it properly again. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the new .zip file containing your code to the S3 bucket?

Comment: Yup, uploaded it to my own bucket I created for it. Made it public. Did I need some special settings first?

Comment: What makes you think Lambda "can't unpack it anymore"? Also, the Lambda function source zip file doesn't need to be, and ordinarily should not be, public.

Comment: Alright, tried it with default settings, and this still happens

"Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again."

Comment: Try `winrar a -afzip c:\upload.zip ...` or use a regular zip program (zip or winzip).

Comment: Yup, you were right, zips are allowed not rars, lmao

Answer (score 1):

Using Linux

`zip -qr target.zip source-folder`

Using windows install 7z.

`7z a -tzip target.zip source-folder`